# transform a multiple normal loop into a parallel loop with foreach

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing

how can i transform a normal loop into a parallel loop whith **foreach** package?

i try to transform this code from **vrtest** package

```
CvMexpb <- matrix(0,nrow=B,ncol=2)

           for(k in 1:B)
           {
            eb <- e * Mammen2(n)
            eb <- eb - mean(eb)
            tem <- 0

           for( j in 1:(n-1) ) 
           { 
           aux2 <- 1/((j*pi)*(j*pi))
           aux2 <- aux2/(n-j+1)
           tem <- tem+aux2* t(eb[(1+j):n]) %*% weiexp[1:(n-j),1:(n-j)] %*% eb[(1+j):n]
           }

           CvMexpb[k,] <- cbind(tem/v > CvMexp,tem/v)
           }    

        pboot <- mean(CvMexpb[,1])
        Critboot <- quantile(CvMexpb[,2],c(0.9,0.95,0.99))
        return(pboot)
```

into

```
CvMexpb <- foreach(k = 1:B, .combine='cbind') %:%
           {
            eb <- e * Mammen2(n)
            eb <- eb - mean(eb)
            tem <- 0

           foreach(j = 1:(n-1), .combine='c') %dopar%
           { 
           aux2 <- 1/((j*pi)*(j*pi))
           aux2 <- aux2/(n-j+1)
           tem <- tem+aux2* t(eb[(1+j):n]) %*% weiexp[1:(n-j),1:(n-j)] %*% eb[(1+j):n]
           }

           CvMexpb[k,] <- cbind(tem/v > CvMexp,tem/v)
           }    

        pboot <- mean(CvMexpb[,1])
        Critboot <- quantile(CvMexpb[,2],c(0.9,0.95,0.99))
        return(pboot)
```

but return an error

> Error in foreach(k = 1:B, .combine = "cbind") %:% { : 
>     "%:%" was passed an illegal right operand

The original full code is

```
compweexp <- 
function(inf) 
{
n <- length(inf)
weiexp <- matrix(1,nrow=n,ncol=n)
for(i in 1:n)
{
    for(j in (i+1):n)
    {
    if(j > n) break
    aux1 <- (inf[i]-inf[j]) %*% t(inf[i]-inf[j])
    weiexp[i,j] <- exp(-0.5*aux1)
    weiexp[j,i] <- weiexp[i,j]
    }
}
return(weiexp)
}

Mammen <-
function(n)
{
p <- (sqrt(5)+1)/(2*sqrt(5))
zmat <- rep(1,n)*(-(sqrt(5)-1)/2);
u <- runif(n,0,1)
zmat[u > p] <- (sqrt(5)+1)/2
return(zmat)
}


Gen.Spec <- 
function(y,B=300)
{
set.seed(12345)
n<- length(y)
e <- y - mean(y)
v <- var(e)
y1 <- y[1:(n-1)]
weiexp <- compweexp(y1)
CvMexp <- 0

for(j in 1:(n-1)) {
   aux2 <- 1/((j*pi)^2)
   aux2 <- aux2/(n-j+1)
   CvMexp <- CvMexp+ aux2* t(e[(1+j):n]) %*% weiexp[1:(n-j),1:(n-j)] %*% e[(1+j):n]
}
CvMexp <- CvMexp/v

CvMexpb <- matrix(0,nrow=B,ncol=2)
for(k in 1:B)
{
    eb <- e * Mammen(n)
    eb <- eb - mean(eb)
    tem <- 0
    for( j in 1:(n-1) ){
    aux2 <- 1/((j*pi)^2)
    aux2 <- aux2/(n-j+1)
    tem <- tem+aux2* t(eb[(1+j):n]) %*% weiexp[1:(n-j),1:(n-j)] %*% eb[(1+j):n]
    }
    CvMexpb[k,] <- cbind(tem/v > CvMexp,tem/v)

}    

pboot <- mean(CvMexpb[,1])
Critboot <- quantile(CvMexpb[,2],c(0.9,0.95,0.99))
return(pboot)
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's causing the error, but I recomment changing CvMexpb[k,] <- cbind(tem/v > CvMexp,tem/v) to just cbind(tem/v > CvMexp,tem/v); that path is either redundant, or will actively break your code

Answer (score 0):

You're getting an error message because the right argument to the '%:%' operator must be another foreach expression.  There isn't a standard way to include initialization code for the inner foreach loop.  The doMPI package does provide such a mechanism.

But another problem is that your inner for-loop can't be parallelized in this way because you're setting the "tem" variable from the value computed in the previous iteration of the loop.  You can solve both problems by only using foreach for the outer loop:

```
CvMexpb <- foreach(k=1:B, .combine='rbind', .export='Mammen2') %dopar% {
  eb <- e * Mammen2(n)
  eb <- eb - mean(eb)
  tem <- 0
  for( j in 1:(n-1) )
  {
    aux2 <- 1/((j*pi)*(j*pi))
    aux2 <- aux2/(n-j+1)
    tem <- tem+aux2* t(eb[(1+j):n]) %*% weiexp[1:(n-j),1:(n-j)] %*% eb[(1+j):n]
  }
  cbind(tem/v > CvMexp,tem/v)
}
```

This will result in fewer tasks that take longer to compute, which may or may not be a good thing.

Comment: Thanks Steve Weston and @RyanGrannell, I will try this!

Comment: I made the suggested changes in the code and the error not occurred.
However, the end result is incorrect! I added the full code in question to facilitate the understanding.

Comment: That's probably because I incorrectly used `.combine="cbind"` when I should have used "rbind".  Sorry about that.